# Maximum elements in ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have this code

```
function saveData(field){

value_insert = $("#"+field).val();
<?php echo "num_to_change =".$_SESSION['numero_paciente'].";";?>
<?php echo "hospital_to_change ='".$_SESSION['hospital']."';";?>

console.log(value_insert+" "+num_to_change+" "+field+" "+hospital_to_change);

 $.ajax({
        data: {"num_to_change" : num_to_change, "hospital_to_change" : hospital_to_change,"field" : field, "value_insert": value_insert},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "saveVariables.php",
    })
     .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.log( "Correct." );
        console.log(data);
     })
     .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
         console.log( "Error: " +  textStatus);
    });
```

}

What I'm trying to do is to send to "saveVariables.php" the variables:

- field, which I get directly from the input that triggers this function
- value_insert, which I get with jquery from the same input as before
- num_to_change, which I get from a session variable
- hospital_to_change, which I get from a session variable as well

But sometimes, most of the times but not ALL the times (which is driving my crazy) I get this result: "**Error: parsererror**"

Few curious behaviours of my code:

- If I delete ONE of the elements I have to send (either field, num_to_change,value_insert or hospital_to_change) it works smoothly. As soon as I add the var again (I need all 4) it throws the same error again
- It dosen't happen always. Let's say 90% of the times. And I always try the same kind of values.

Extra information:

1. The "console.log" you see at line 7 always shows the correct values
2. I'm not sending tons of information inside those 4 variables, it is always something like:

   - value_insert -> 23
   - hospital_to_change -> Primero
   - num_to_change -> 22
   - field -> mmhg

The thing that deleting one variable makes the code work confuses me... Is there a maximum number of variables I can send this way? It does not have any sense, because sometimes works, but I can't think of anythig else..

---

SOLVED ALREADY:

The error "Error: parseerror" was being sent by my php code, not my ajax one, so now I started my php code again step by step and everything works fine.

Comment: Don't you need to `JSON.stringify()` the data you are sending?

Comment: Please provide the PHP code where the error actually occurs.

Comment: `"Error: parsererror"` means your server doesn't return valid JSON notation

Comment: Oh, so you mean it is not the sent information but the recieved one?

Comment: @MiguelCantóBataller That's what mean the error... If you comment `//dataType: "json",`, what do you get?!

Comment: I see! Now it works because i commented my php code, which I assume is the one that actually has an error.
If I comment dataType: "json"it works as well

Comment: TY guys, I though the error was in my javascript code

Comment: A. Wolf if you respond I upvote your solution. Your comment ""Error: parsererror" means your server doesn't return valid JSON notation" was the useful one.